# HightChart - Width Columns

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Hi I am having a problem like this:

I want the width of the columns to be 26px. I use pointWidth=26 and it's done.

But it has the problem that the columns are not next to each other.

How can I fix the problem?

This is my code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-field-rnt0bx?file=/src/App.tsx:0-3136

I want result like this. columns are next to each other. Here is the illustration
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVmtU.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Instead of linking to you code, please add the appropriate code in you question instead. You can checkout [mre] on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the columns by using the `pointPlacement` property:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  pointPlacement: 0.12
},
{
  ...,
  pointPlacement: -0.12
}]
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2e3rawgu/

But if your chart has dynamic width, you need to set the positions by custom code, for example:

```
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          series = this.series,
          plotLeft = this.plotLeft;

        const correctPosition = (points, correction) => {
          points.forEach(point => {
            point.graphic.attr({
              x: xAxis.toPixels(point.x) - plotLeft + correction
            });
          });
        }

        correctPosition(series[0].points, -POINT_WIDTH);
        correctPosition(series[1].points, 0);
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ae2htc0z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement